# Why is there an err parsing this DDL, and why can't the engine be more specific about locating it?

Tags: c#, sql, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

With this DDL ("BLA" is a tablename in the form "CCR130329093342")

```
ALTER TABLE BLA ADD salvation float NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT
```

...I'm getting, "*There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number, Token line offset,, Token in error,,]*"

Okay, then, which line number? offset? It knows/thinks there's a problem, but can't or won't say what or where.

Is there anything obviously wrong with this DDL? Should it be this instead:

```
ALTER TABLE BLA ADD salvation float NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT 0.0
```

?

### UPDATE

If I revert the DDL back to the original simple type (without adding "NOT NULL", simply "alter bla add blah nvarchar(12)" I don't get the "query could not be parsed" msg *except* in the one that declares a float (shown above)...does SQL-Server-CE hate on floats, or...???

Comment: Remove WITH from the statement

Comment: Okay, I'll do that - does the 0.0 need to encased in parens, as Mojo indicated?

Comment: I think you have a hater, Clay. All of your posts are getting downvoted.

Comment: I noticed that. It's probably somebody in North Korea.

Comment: @jp2code: Fortunately, the vote system will identify it at some point and "fix" it.

Answer (score 3):

default needs a value:

```
alter table bla add salvation float not null with default(0.0)
```

Comment: I was wondering about that, and encased in parens, no less...I'll try it out.