# Why is this function failing with "There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number, Token line offset,, Token in error,,]"?

Tags: c#, sql, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, .net-1.0

This code:

```
public bool IsValidColumn(string tableName, string columnName)
{
    //return true;// <-- when I uncomment this, I don't get the err msg (but I don't know whether it's a valid column or not, either)
    bool validColumn = false;
    string tblQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = @columnName";
    checkConnection();
    try
    {
        SqlCeCommand cmd = objCon.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = tblQuery;
        SqlCeParameter tblNameParam = new SqlCeParameter("@tableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128);
        tblNameParam.Value = tableName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(tblNameParam);
        SqlCeParameter colNameParam = new SqlCeParameter("@columnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128);
        colNameParam.Value = tableName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(colNameParam);
        //int i = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        int i = 0;
        object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if ((obj != null) && (obj != DBNull.Value)) 
        {
            i = Int32.Parse(obj.ToString());
            validColumn = i > 0;
        } 
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NULL returned from ExecuteScalar. Remove this line.");
        }
    }
    catch (SqlCeException sqlceex)
    {
        return false; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return validColumn;
}
```

...was adapted from/based on an earlier answer here: [How can I determine whether a column exists in a SQL Server CE table with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693639/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-column-exists-in-a-sql-server-ce-table-with-c)

And yet, it causes me to get, "There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number, Token line offset,, Token in error,,]" (which I complained about here: [Why is there an err parsing this DDL, and why can't the engine be more specific about locating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707487/why-is-there-an-err-parsing-this-ddl-and-why-cant-the-engine-be-more-specific) and here:

[SQL Server CE's DDL parser is very picky but secretive about what it is finding fault with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713194/sql-server-ces-ddl-parser-is-very-picky-but-secretive-about-what-it-is-finding)).

In my attempts to get to the bottom of what was causing this err msg, I've actually refactored the legacy code a fair amount (threw a lot of rancid spaghetti out of the fridge), so it hasn't been a waste of time, but now I find that what was causing that err msg was something in the code above. So the question is: How *can* I determine whether a column is valid without generating this err msg?

Comment: Does tje query work if you run it directly against the db?

Comment: I don't know - I don't have direct access to the DB that way (archaic tools, coding/debugging by the seat of my britches).

Comment: It does seem likely to be the cause of the error you're getting but this seems wrong to me: `colNameParam.Value = tableName;`.

Comment: why is the .Execute line commented out..? also I would highly recommend using Parameters.AddWithValue method.. let the Database handle the data type.. your current code `Clay` needs some serious refactoring..

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: If you think that about *this* code, you should see the rest of it. I actually felt I was being driven insane a couple of weeks ago trying to grok this stuff all day long. Admittedly, that would have been a short ride, but still - it's above and beyond the call of duty to lose your insanity to code some unknown cat wrote.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: Only the old .ExecuteScalar() is commented out; the new one is alive and well.

Comment: @500: Good catch! Maybe because the "column" didn't exist, it was causing the error; I'll find out tomorrow.

Comment: Of course what I meant to say was "does NOT" :)

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: AddWithValue() does not seem to be available in .NET 1.1

Comment: didn't realize that was `1.1` perhaps you can update your `Tags`

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: There is no .NET 1.1 tag.

Comment: @500: Actually, that did solve that particular problem. Now I have a slew of others, though: The specified table already exists
There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number,Token line offset,,Token in error,,]
SQL Server CE does not support parallel transactions.
StackOverflowException
The resource 216 was not found in System.Data.resources

Comment: There *are* `.NET-1.0` and `.NET-1.1` tags.  You might try adding the 1.0 tag (again, there never was a CF 1.1) to help minimize confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, I see this message:

> SQL Server CE does not support parallel transactions.

I'm guessing your code is calling this check while you are inside a transaction. You may need to do your error checking separately from your transactions.

I used transactions for a while, then realized they weren't really needed for simple read/write operations to the database ...since I wasn't dealing with a banking institution. I'd bet it would be safe to remove your transaction statements, but that's just side comments.

I notice a lot of your code uses these specialized statements:

- `checkConnection()`,
- `objCon.CreateCommand()` and
- `isValidField`.

Are these really helping you?

How many places are you calling these routines?

The error message makes it sound like you have already started another transaction somewhere else in your code before you called `IsValidColumn`.

Perhaps you could modify the code to check `IsValidColumn` early on (like when the program starts) so that you already know the column is valid before starting your transactions.

Comment: No, none of this code is helping me; it's a garbagetruckload of rancid spaghetti that I look upon with wide-eyed trembling. I just want to rush in to this hall of horrors, grab something, run out, and slam the door, hopefully never to return. If you look up "whack-a-mole" in the dictionary, it refers you to this project. What this code needs most is an exorcist.

Comment: You've definitely got a following of people who don't don't like you, though!